# WPF Grid: Is there an easy way to readjust the row items if I need to insert new rows?

Tags: wpf, insert, grid, row

It appears that grid row and column definitions are hard-coded like this:

```
Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"
```

I am in the middle of development on a new WPF app and I am having to constantly add and delete new rows from my grid as the client makes up their mind on how the form should look.  I am discovering that this is quite a tedious task.  If insert a row near the top, I have to manually change all the row indexes in the XAML beneath the row I just inserted.

Is there an easy way to auto-adjust all the rows?

Comment: If 2010, you use the designer to add or remove a row/column it will adjust everythin for you. Right click where you want the new row select row then insert. This is one of the few things that the designer does well and easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Grid` is a *grid* and the rows and columns are numbered for a specific reason.  It's like a piece of graph paper sliced up into a fixed numbers of squares.  Because the numbers of rows and columns is fixed you can do powerful things like row and column spanning.  Conversely, this is **not** flexible for a variable number of rows or columns.

If you need a variable number of rows, or you are continually adding rows at design time, then it may be that the `Grid` is not the best design element for you.  Or better still, you can use the `Grid` in combination with another layout element to get the flexibility you need.

For example, you can put all your variable rows into a single `Grid` row and now your grid row count doesn't change any more.  But then you will need a layout element that supports a variable number of rows to put into that `Grid` row.  Well, there are a lot of them to choose from but two for example that are useful are `StackPanel` and `DockPanel`.

The layout element `DockPanel` in particular is very powerful for variable numbers of rows or columns, particularly when used as `DockPanels` within `DockPanels` or other combinations.  All you need to handle this layout problem is to **subdivide and conquer**!

Here's an introduction to `DockPanel`: [WPF Tutorial: Dock Panel](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DockPanel.html)

Comment: I just now got around to this and your stackpanel idea works great.  I set up a stackpanel with vertical orientation to serve as my table.  I then use a series of horizontal stackpanels within each of those to serve as the rows, each having two controls, a label and a textbox.  To make sure the labels are all the same width, I create a style to set their width properties.  Now moving rows around is a breeze!

Comment: This doesn't answer the actual issue here - that it's very annoying/tedious to have to update row-indices whenever you want to add or remove a row to a Grid. Even if it's just a few times during design it's still tedious. PatFromCanada's comment is a much better answer - use the designer instead.

Answer (score 75):

In Visual Studio 2015 you can also hover over the edge of a row and a little dropdown box will appear. When you click the down arrow two of the options are "move row before" and "move row after". That's the best way I've found.

Example image:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: great! if you could include a screenshot in your answer that would be much appreciated.

Comment: This answer is legendary, you have no idea what a time saver this is.  Thank you!

Comment: This directly addresses and solves the stated problem. It should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Years. YEARS, I've been plagued by this. I was just about to write an extension to do it. Thank goodness I found this answer first.

Comment: Extremely Superb answer. Thanks for saving lot's of time of many people. A real time saver.

Comment: Is there any shortcut key combination?

Comment: What is even better that you can actually add new row before and after or delete it and all the rows are recalculated. Is this one of the instances, where saying that working with 
 VS designer is harmful for WPF?

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to auto-adjust your rows/columns for a `Grid`.

A potential alternative that I've used in the past is a `UniformGrid` since it doesn't need a Row/Column reference in each item. It's nice for blocking out placeholders for the data.

If you are doing initial designs, I'd recommend just using the Drag/Drop interface in visual studio or a design tool like [Balsamiq](http://balsamiq.com/) or [Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/blend_overview.aspx). Balsamiq is my favorite since it intentionally doesn't look like an actual application, so clients don't get hung up on the actual appearance of the thing and focus on the data instead.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a super old question but in case anyone else comes across it, in Visual Studio 2013 (maybe earlier too I'm not sure) you can just hover over the edge of the grid and it will let you split a row into two rows.

It will make the rows a set number height so you will probably need to go back and change then to 'Auto' or '*' or whatever you would like to use.  It also makes anything in the original row span both rows so you would need to remove the RowSpan="2" attribute on those items and put them into the correct rows, but it will push all items in lower rows down automatically.

It's not fully automatic and there is a little cleanup, but if you have a lot of rows it's faster than renumbering everything manually.