# VS/WPF: how to increment all grid.column after you've inserted a new column ?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

When I edit (the text of) a xaml using Visual studio I often add a new column (or line).

It's quite boring and inefficient to have to go through all the columns (or lines) to increment them.
Is there a visual studio native function (or do you know of a plugin) that does it ?

(I supposed this has been asked before but I can't find the correct keywords to get the response).

Comment: You shouldn't put tags in your title.

Comment: Correct answer is 'Please pay attention that SO is too dumb to escape the tags for you' :)

Comment: What do you mean by adding a new column (or line) and incrementing it? Ar you talking about adding columns to a Grid? Or are you talking about adding lines in XAML and indenting them? In the last case, you can use the `Edit.FormatDocument` command by pressing Ctrl+K and then Ctrl+D.

Comment: it's not about indenting.Say I got <textbox Grid.row="1" /><textbox Grid.row="2" />. I insert a button between the two ( = I type <Button Grid.row=2 />). Instead of having <textbox Grid.row="1" /><Button Grid.row=2 /><textbox Grid.row="2" /> I want this to be turned into <textbox Grid.row="1" /><Button Grid.row=2 /><textbox Grid.row="3" /> (note the grid.row="3" for last item)

Answer (score 1):

Old question, I know, but landed here and then found this answer which I think answers the question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45228899/1581933

i.e. hover over the edge of the grid, click the down arrow, click 'Add Row Before'. The Grid.Rows will now auto renumber.

Comment: it is rather than a comment instead of posting as an answer link in answering to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are 100% right, that is stupid design of Grid row layout...

The XAML designer should have function to auto reorder all Grid row or Grid column values.